# Flutter / VS - Emulator is booting up - error

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, simulator

While the ios simulator is booting (Emulator is booting up - message in the virtual studio) and also launched in the background it is visible but not shown in the devices list (bottom right) of visual studio.

`flutter doctor` command in the terminal shows no errors for Xcode, see output below. Also, notice the system info here:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.2, on Mac OS X 10.12.6 16G29, locale    de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific  functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.23.0)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issuesfound!
```

The Android Simulator is recognized, when started and shows up in the devices list of visual studio.

How to implement the ios simulators (Xcode 9), too?

Comment: Virtual Studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio, Thx!